# How to keep Zend_Debug HTML tags out of Zend_Log

Tags: zend-framework, zend-log

I use Zend_Debug::dump to dump variables into a Zend_Log file.  How can I get it to stop wrapping the output in HTML tags?

The documentaion says "If the output stream is detected as a web presentation, the output of var_dump() is escaped using » htmlspecialchars() and wrapped with (X)HTML  tags."  Why does it think my log file is a web presentation?

The method for the dump function has a boolean $echo flag.  Even when this is FALSE, I get HTML markup in my log files.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Debug is always using htmlspecialchars() to quote. You cant disable this by an provided parameter.

The boolean for "echo" is only used to disable the var_dump() (wich is used in Zend_Debug) printing to the browser.

Code from Zend_Debug::dump():

$output = htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_QUOTES);

```
    if (self::getSapi() == 'cli') {
        $output = PHP_EOL . $label
                . PHP_EOL . $output
                . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        if(!extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
            $output = htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_QUOTES);
        }

        $output = '<pre>'
                . $label
                . $output
                . '</pre>';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  So do you just wade through the html tags when reviewing logs?  Or do you log to a DB?

Comment: no is use : error_log(print_r($error, true)); instead of zend debug ;)